# Using transmute_at with integer column in data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

can I apply `transmute_at` to a column of integers in a dataframe, without getting an error?

Is there any other option, besides changing in advance that specific column to a double precision?

MWE of successful application:

```
df <- data.frame("date" = seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct(format(Sys.time(),"%F %T"),tz="UTC"),length.out=20,by="min"), "a.1" = as.double(seq(1,40,2)), "a.2" = rnorm(20,1,2), "b.1"= rnorm(20,1,4), "b.2"= rnorm(20,3,4))

df %>%
    transmute_at(vars(matches('a.1|a.2')), ~ case_when(. < 1.5 ~ NA_real_,
                                                       TRUE~ .)) %>% 
    rename_at(vars(matches('a.1|a.2')), function(x) paste0(x,".clean")) %>% ## rename the clean Bs columns
    bind_cols(df[,grep("b.|date",names(df))], .) -> df.2 ##bind cols to df with clean and dirty columns
```

MWE of failing application

```
    df <- data.frame("date" = seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct(format(Sys.time(),"%F %T"),tz="UTC"),length.out=20,by="min"), "a.1" = as.integer(seq(1,40,2)), "a.2" = rnorm(20,1,2), "b.1"= rnorm(20,1,4), "b.2"= rnorm(20,3,4))

df %>%
    transmute_at(vars(matches('a.1|a.2')), ~ case_when(. < 1.5 ~ NA_real_,
                                                       TRUE~ .)) %>% 
    rename_at(vars(matches('a.1|a.2')), function(x) paste0(x,".clean")) %>% ## rename the clean Bs columns
    bind_cols(df[,grep("b.|date",names(df))], .) -> df.2 ##bind cols to df with clean and dirty columns
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option where we coerce the `NA` to the correct type by multiplying with one of the elements of the column

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  transmute_at(vars(matches('^a\\.[1-2]$')), 
                       list(clean = ~case_when(. < 1.5 ~ NA *.[1],
                                                    TRUE~ .)))
```